Laravel ErrorException Undefinex Array Key 1 - getRequestPortFromLine($line) and Carbon::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s Y', $matches[1]);
im working with Laravel and I got sometimes an error while in production. I use php artisan serve --host XXX.XXX.X.XX --port XX command and sometimes the service crash and this error appears on cmd. Can someone help me fix this problem? Thanks a lot
Laravel v.10.48
PHP 8.2.4
Composer 2.7.1
ErrorException 

  Undefined array key 1

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:328
    324▕                 $line = str_replace('  ', ' ', $line);
    325▕                 
    326▕                 preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);
    327▕
  ➜ 328▕                return Carbon::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s Y', $matches[1]);  
    329▕                 }
    330▕
    331▕                 /**
    332 |                 * Get the request port from the given PHP server output.

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:328
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}("Undefined array key 0", "C:\Users\ict\Desktop\intranet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php")        

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php:264
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::getDateFromLine("XX.X.XX:51140 Accepted")

and this
ErrorException 

  Undefined array key 1

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:344
    340▕     protected function getRequestPortFromLine($line)
    341▕     {
    342▕         preg_match('/:(\d+)\s(?:(?:\w+$)|(?:\[.*))/', $line, $matches);
    343▕
  ➜ 344▕         return (int) $matches[1];
    345▕     }
    346▕
    347▕     /**
    348▕      * Get the console command options.

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:344
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}("Undefined array key 1", "C:\Users\ict\Desktop\intranet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:272
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::getRequestPortFromLine(" Closing")

I tried to upgrade my PHP and Laravel version, I tried to update my composer but nothing changed. Can someone help me please?

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Composer itself? I would assume that you have to check the inputs that cause this failure

@NicoHaase these are vendor function so I just tried to upgrade my php/laravel/composer but nothing changed

Even if these are methods in the vendor folder, maybe they get called with inaccurate data?

php artisan serve is NOT meant for production.

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/48590, you're not the first one facing such problems

Or https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/48547

After all, if you are facing a bug when you haven't written any code on your own that could cause this bug, please report it to the maintainers of Laravel

@NicoHaase thanks for your help but I've already take a look on that links but there's no solution...

@Olivier I got same error if im in local

Use a real web server like Apache, even on localhost.

Problem solved using Apache, thanks
